# Splitting a string in Python using a condition

Tags: python, string

Here are my strings

```
    vishal.testzone.com
    important.testzone.com
    ram.testzone.com
```

What I need to do is split the part of the string before the first dot and store it in a variable and leave the rest. I saw string slicing but I'm not sure how it can be used for my condition. I know there are a lot of similar questions but none of them has a condition like mine.Is there any other option like string slicing to achieve this.

Comment: `"vishal.testzone.com".split(".")[0]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using [split()](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) ?

```
s = "vishal.testzone.com"
vishal = s.split('.', 1)[0]
```

(edited per comment below from *jpp*).

Comment: Since only one split is required, you should specify the operational parameter for `str.split`.

Answer (score 3):

To split only the first token before '.':

```
before, rest = "vishal.testzone.com".split('.', 1)
print before, rest
```